# Finding the index of a field with its name using arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy, shapefile, fields-attributes, list

I want to extract the index of a field with its name using arcpy. It seems what I have written is so dumb. Is there any simpler method with out using for-loop?

```
    import arcpy

    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(self.address_ref_layer1)
    self.field_name = []
    for field in fieldList:
        self.field_name.append(field.name)
    #self.remove_pseudo_nodes()
    print self.field_name
    print self.field_name.index(u"NAMN1")
```

It could also be written:

```
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(self.address_ref_layer1
    name_index = [f.name for f in fieldList].index(u"NAMN1")
```

The ListFiled function returns list of field objects with many properties as well as name, but no function to return the index of the field which has a specific name?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to investigate the [FieldMappings](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000078000000) object, which has various methods which deal with indices.

Instead of using for loops, you can use [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), like so:

```py
self.field_name = [field.name for field in fieldList]
```

It can be shortened even further, since you may not need to store fieldList at all:

```py
self.field_name = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(self.address_ref_layer1)]
```

Comment: I have never used FieldMappings, but as I understand it is mainly used for merging data sets.

Comment: @msc87, yes it is generally used for that. But it's likely the easiest way to concisely get all the information about fields that you'll want.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to find an answer for this on the ESRI sites which is why I ended up here. The clue is the object has field.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
FC = r'Your_FC'
indexes = arcpy.ListIndexes(FC)
    for index in indexes:
        for fieldname in index.fields:
        fieldname = fieldname.name
        indexname = index.name
        print fieldname, indexname
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the field index number with `FieldMapping`:

```
def get_field_index(table, fieldName):
    # Return: the index number of the fieldName in the table.
    field_map = arcpy.FieldMappings()
    field_map.addTable(table)
    field_index = field_map.findFieldMapIndex(fieldName)
    return field_index
```

Answer (score 0):

This Python function will return the Index Name associated with the FeatureClass and Field Name passed in.

```
def getIndexName(fieldname,fc):
    indexes = arcpy.ListIndexes(fc)
    for index in indexes:
        for f in index.fields:
            if f.name.upper() == fieldname.upper():
                return index.name
```

Comment: Hi  Klewis , i am trying to use your code to get the fieldindex. Why do i get an AttributeError: no attribute 'upper' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a function that will return the index of a field:

```
import arcpy
def findindex(table,fieldname):
    return [i.name for i in arcpy.ListFields(table)].index(fieldname)
```

Input a feature class or table and the field name:

```
>>>findindex(r'C:\GIS\Test.shp','EKOSTAT')
8
```